# Displaying SQL Server database value in Gridview showing error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, gridview

When I try to display database values in a gridview I get an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'.

And code is

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataAdapter adap;
    DataSet ds;

    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(
      @"Data Source=DILIPWIN\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=radb;Integrated Security=True");
    cn.Open();

    var home = new Home();
    adap = new SqlDataAdapter(
      "select roll_num, mark from marks where mark < 50 and dept_id=" + 
       home.cboxDept.SelectedValue + "  and sem_id=" + home.cboxSem.SelectedValue + 
      " and subject_id=" + home.cboxSubject.SelectedValue + " and batch_id= " + 
       home.cboxBatch.SelectedValue + " and cls_id=" + home.cboxClass.SelectedValue, cn);

    ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
    adap.Fill(ds, "dataGridView1");

    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

Comment: Can you post the query after all the concatenation?

Comment: I assume you are working a __WinForms__ and actually are using a __DataGridView__?? Please __always tag appropriately__ or else you waste __WPF__ folks' time! (and vice versa..)

Answer (score 1):

Use sql-parameters which probably solves this issue and also prevents future sql-injection issues:

```
string sql = @"
SELECT roll_num, 
       mark 
FROM   marks 
WHERE  mark < 50 
AND    dept_id=@dept_id
AND    sem_id=@sem_id 
AND    subject_id=@subject_id 
AND    batch_id=@batch_id 
AND    cls_id=@cls_id;";

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using(var cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DILIPWIN\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=radb;Integrated Security=True"))
using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cn))
{ 
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dept_id", home.cboxDept.SelectedValue );
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sem_id", home.cboxSem.SelectedValue );
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject_id", home.cboxSubject.SelectedValue );
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@batch_id", home.cboxBatch.SelectedValue );
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cls_id", home.cboxClass.SelectedValue );
    da.Fill(ds);  // you don't need to open/close the connection with Fill
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

You should also use the correct types. [`AddWithValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) will try to infer the type from the value. So if those are `int`s you should parse them accordingly (`int.Parse(home.cboxdept.SelectedValue )`).

Answer (score 0):

Use are missing to call databind method here.Use following code :

```
GridView1.DataBind();//This line is missing in your code`
```

try the below format

```
 DataAdapter adapter=new DataAdapter(SqlCommand,SqlConn);
 DataTable tbl=new Datatable();
 adapter.Fill(tbl);
 GridView1.DataSource=tbl;
 GridView1.DataBind();//This line is missing in your code
```

`

Comment: _"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'."_ It's also winforms not webforms.